# Pass subject, content, etc with node.js

Tags: circuit-sdk

How can I pass subject content in the node.js using add.textitem node?
I have tried the code below but the bot only sends the content, I never get subject, parentItemId, etc..

```
var content = {
    subject: 'test',
    content: msg.payload,
}
msg.payload = content;
return msg;
```

Debugging

```
04/09/2019 17:42:58node: 8de0d86f.987558
msg.payload : Object
object
subject: "test"
content: "All arrays Chuck Norris declares are of infinite size, because Chuck Norris knows no bounds."
contentType: "Circuit.Enums.TextItemContentType.RICH"
```

But in Circuit, only get content.

Comment: Can you show more of your code? Are you using the REST API or the JS SDK? If the JS SDK, then see the example here: https://circuitsandbox.net/sdk/classes/Client.html#method_addTextItem

Comment: Hello Roger.

As I don't know to much about JS/REST, etc, I'm using node-red to do this integration using circuit modules. This is based on JS SDK.

This is the code I'm sending to addtextItem node.

var text = {
    subject: 'test',
    content: msg.payload,
    contentType: 'Circuit.Enums.TextItemContentType.RICH'
}
msg.payload = text;
return msg;

Content works great, but subject, parentID and attachments not.

Answer (score 0):

The content of the text item needs to be passed as the `msg.payload.content`. Here you are trying to pass the object as the payload itself. See the code below for how to use pass the subject and content.

```
msg.payload = {
    content: {
        content: 'content',
        subject: 'subject'
    }
}
return msg;
```

Comment: Tks Richard! Works fine!